# Seleccionar los valores mayores de una columna omitiendo los menores y crear una subconsulta

Tags: sql

Buen día ,

El objetivo es seleccionar siempre el valor mayor o ultimo registrado de la columna (ScanNum)
este va incrementando con cada insert

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es sacar el tiempo transcurrido entre escaneo (ultimo y nuevo), dejo algunos ejemplos que intente

```
select
    Nombre,ScanNum,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Ultimo_scan,GETDATE()) as minutos
from
    QTY_SCAN
where
    (ScanNum > (select MIN(ScanNum)from QTY_SCAN)) 

select
    Nombre,ScanNum
from
    QTY_SCAN
where
    ScanNum=(select MAX(ScanNum) from QTY_SCAN)
```

al final lo que necesito es solo calcular los últimos valores de la columna ScanNum que representa la ultima orden escaneada por el usuario, el cual ira incrementando con cada escaneo 1,2,3,4,5, etc.

utilizo este query para hacerlo pero me muestra todos los registros , solo necesito calcular los últimos registros (registros seleccionados en azul).

select Nombre,Orden as ultima_orden_escaneada,ScanNum as numero_de_escaneos,DATEDIFF(minute,Ultimo_scan,getdate()) as tiempo_transcurrido_de_ultimo_escaneo from QTY_SCAN where Area='mod'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las posibilidades que dispones, es utilizar la función [row_number](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/) para numerar las filas.

Primero el escenario:

```
Create table qty_scan
             (
             id           int
           , Orden        varchar(10)
           , Num_operador smallint
           , Nombre       varchar(25)
           , Area         char(3)
           , Turno        tinyint
           , Ultimo_Scan   datetime
           , ScanNum      tinyint
             );
```

Ahora los datos

```
Insert into qty_scan
        (
        id, 
        Orden, 
        Num_operador, 
        Nombre, 
        Area,
        Turno,
        Ultimo_Scan, 
        ScanNum
        )
values
(1,'XO563',2010,'sanchez t','mod',1,'20220222 11:15:14.700',1),
(2,'XO258',2010,'sanchez t','mod',1,'20220222 11:35:17.753',1),
(3,'PO123',2010,'perez a  ','mod',1,'20220222 11:05:14.700',1),
(4,'PO456',2010,'perez a  ','mod',1,'20220222 11:20:17.753',1),
(5,'PO456',2010,'perez a  ','mod',1,'20220222 11:40:17.753',1);
```

Ahora vamos a montar una tabla de expresión común que numere todas las filas, partiiconando por el nombre de usuario (ojo este criterio, es porque en función de los datos, es el más apropiado, pero lo suyo sería tener algo que fuera único). Y numere ordenando por la fecha de último escaneo y el escaneo en caso de empate y por último el id, para que el orden sea determinista.

De la resolución, solo recogemos la fila uno de cada partición.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Nombre
        order by Ultimo_Scan desc, ScanNum desc, id)
        as rn
    FROM qty_scan
    )
    SELECT CTE.Nombre As nombre, 
           CTE.Orden As ultima_orden_escaneada,
           CTE.ScanNum As numero_de_escaneo,
           DATEDIFF(minute,CTE.Ultimo_Scan,getdate()) AS Tiempo_Transcurrido
        FROM CTE 
    where rn=1;
```

Resultado

[image: Result]

La columna del `tiempo transcurrido`, no tengo claro del todo, que sea lo que buscas, pero de los intentos, es lo que he entendido.

Comment: Muy buena tu respuesta y bien explicada me sirvió bastante para lo que estoy buscando, muchas gracias.